# Unhandled exception type ScriptException

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, ejb

In injecting javascript in ejb project I get this error:

> Unhandled exception type ScriptException.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void testeEjb() {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    // create a JavaScript engine
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    // evaluate JavaScript code from String
    try {
        engine.eval("print('Hello, World')");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Comment: I don't think your javascript has the correct syntax. Try console.log() instead of print().

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace of exception? And which version of JVM is used?

Comment: Syntax is correct. I think you probably have the wrong import for `ScriptException`. Make sure it is `javax.script.ScriptException`.

Comment: @dambros I haven't seen print() used like this, is it just a shortcut for window.print() ?

Comment: @ewanc I don't know JS to answer you that. The thing is this snippet will print to the console. ScriptEngine is rather obscure to me, because you can use both Java and the selected language syntax and it will work.

Comment: @dambros no problem, I just hadn't seen it before and found it interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the correct imports:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```